# NSDateFormatter setDateFormat is not returning value correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

In my app, I have below code:

```
if ([fieldValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
                [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
                resultValue = [formatter dateFromString:fieldValue];
            }
```

fieldValue is set from a datePicker and let's say the value I got is `"2016-03-12 01:13:36 +0000"`

In my code, I initialized new NSDateFormatter and called setDateFormat function to set the resultValue in form of "MM/dd/yyyy". For example, 01/13/2016.

However, the value I'm getting for resultValue is also `2016-03-12 01:13:36 +0000`.

I'm not sure why this formatter is not working correctly.

Comment: And what is your timezone?????

Comment: Why do you think `resultValue` isn't correct? It is.

Comment: @rmaddy, if it is correct, why isn't it returning in format of "01/13/2016"

Comment: @HotLicks, pacific time zone

Comment: Why would it be? You converted a string in that format to an `NSDate`. When you log an `NSDate`, it always shows in the format you are seeing. If you want the `NSDate` shown in a specific format then you need to convert the `NSDate` to an `NSString` using an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: And, if it's 1/13/2016 in the Pacific timezone, what's the date in Greenwich England?

Comment: @HotLicks The question is about the format. This isn't a timezone question.

Comment: Ah, yes! Missed that.  He's using `/` instead of `-`.  (And, of course, he's no doubt failed to account for timezone.)

Comment: @rmaddy, so the problem is that I'm returning the date as in String not as in NSDate now.?

Comment: @Kahsn No. Your problem is your confusion about why logging an `NSDate` isn't coming out in the format in your date formatter. You seem to have this all backwards. The code you posted goes from `NSString` to `NSDate`. But if you want a date in specific format, you need to go from `NSDate` to `NSString`. But you already have a string in desired format (`fieldValue`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the right result as @RyanR described above.

In case you still prefer string as input, you need to tell your `formatter` the format of the input, and then convert string to NSDate first

```
let string = "2016-03-12 01:13:36 +0000"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss +zzzz"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(string)
```

Once you have NSDate value, you can convert it to whatever format you like. In your case, if you want to have MM/dd/yyyy, then:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
let resultValue = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

This code above give you exactly what you expected

About date format pattern, you could take a look at [this link](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Several mistakes in your first date format. It should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, UIDatePicker has a property named date that you can get the selected NSDate value straight out of.

```
NSDate *selectedDate = datePicker.date;
```

Your code example is using a string as the source value, that doesn't make sense within the context of the details that you have provided. Are you sure you aren't trying to format an NSDate object into 'MM/dd/yyyy'? It's very unclear what you are trying to accomplish, but if that is the case you'll want to call `-stringFromDate:` and pass it your NSDate instance, like so:

```
NSString *formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling dateFromString. That takes a date STRING the specified format and converts it to an NSDate (an object) An NSDate object does not have an internal format. It is a moment in time, recorded internally as a time in UTF.

Any time you log an NSDate using NSLog (or the debugger "po" or "expression" commands) you will see the date as a string in UTF format, as you show.

If you want the output to be a string, you need to use a date formatter's `stringFromDate` to convert the date to a string

If you want to convert a date string in one format to another format, you have to convert the date string to an `NSDate` using one date formatter's `dateFromString` method, then convert the resulting date to another string using a different date formatter's `stringFromDate` method